# What is the difference between session Id obtained from _generateSessionId() and the one obtained by parsing sockjs._transport._url?

Tags: javascript, websocket, sockjs, stompjs

There are two types of session Id visible in sockjs
One obtained by calling the function _generateSessionId directly on SockJs object returned here
`const sockJs = new SockJs('http://example.com/ws/api')`

and another session Id visible when printing the entire sockJs object in console and parsing `sockJs._transport._url` object inside it which gives us something like this

`ws://example.com/ws/api/333/zf2j9qxe/websocket`

according to my reading, `zf2j9qxe` is the actual session Id which is different than the one returned from the function call previously

Which one is the real one?